# wso2 apim 3.0-m24 token api issue?

Tags: oauth, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I was using apim 3-m18 previously and post'ing to localhost:9443/api/auth/oauth2/v1.0/token?grant_type=password&scope=apim:api_view with the basic auth token of clientid:clientsecret returned from /api/id4entity/oauth2/dcr/v1.0/register endpoint worked fine in giving me the oauth token for admin api's - e.g. the logic laid out at [wso2 API-M 3.0 - how to get oauth token for product/admin api calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49289106/wso2-api-m-3-0-how-to-get-oauth-token-for-product-admin-api-calls)

However, I upgraded to latest rev (m24) and the dcr register endpoint still works fine, but when I then hit the token api with the base64-encoded clientid:clientsecret from dcr, the request hangs before i get a timeout error.

When I exit m24 and restart m18 and make the exact same requests (dcr call for clientid/secret, then token api call), it works.  Then switching to m22 fails with same requests.

I didn't see any documentation or issues in github on this, so was curious if anyone knows what I might need to change to get the oauth token.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please use the following curl command

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic N2Y4MzM0ODEtNjk1ZS00OWY4LTg0OTgtOGU0NjUwNzhmYjljOmU1NmZlOTM3LTQwZjYtNGEwMy04MDIzLTE4ZGE0YmZmNWU3OA==" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'username=admin&password=admin&grant_type=password&scope=scope' "https://localhost:9443/api/auth/oauth2/v1.0/token" -kv
```

Authorization token is Base64 encoded(clientId:clientSecret)

Comment: Thanks - that works - when I had the scope and grant_type params in the url as query params rather than as form parameters, it worked in rev 18, but looks like that changed and now they have to be form params.